# How to insert a big Excel table in a Word document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, embedding

I've tried many times to insert an Excel table with 17 columns in a Word 2010 document without changing the layout.

Please explain the process to insert a big Excel table in a Word document.

Comment: What have you tried? changing column width/ page orientation/ font size? If those don't help please post some example data, your question is too broad now.

Comment: You should probably change that word page to portrait mode and paste the excel table so that it fits for the width of the table

Answer (score 0):

Click on View Tab and choose Draft view. Now you can paste table of any width without disturbing the layout. You still need to format the table in order to print though.